# Log in with flask

Tags: python, flask, logging, flask-login

I'm doing my log in window in my web application. I'm using mysql and flask. I have already made my registration window and everything works. But now when try to log my User, it says my user doesn't exist. I made a flash message, that makes me know that my email or password is wrong, but even when my email and password and email is right it doesn´t work

I want to know why it doesn't recognize my user

this is the classification of my folders:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZjXI.png)

this is the code of my user

```
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash 
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id, nombreu, correou, claveu, perfilu) -> None:
        self.id         = id
        self.nombreu    = nombreu
        self.correou     = correou
        self.claveu     = claveu
        self.perfilu    = perfilu
    
    @classmethod
    def validar_clave(self, clavecifrada,claveu):
        
        return check_password_hash(clavecifrada, claveu)
```

This is the code of model user

```
from models.entities.User import User 

class ModelUser :
    @classmethod
    def login(self, db, usuario):
        try:
            selUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
            selUsuario.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correou = %s", (usuario.correou,))
            u = selUsuario.fetchone()
            if u is not None:
                User(u[0], u[1], u[2], User.validar_clave(u[3], usuario.claveu), u[4])
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex)

    @classmethod 
    def get_by_id(self, db, id):
        try:
            selUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
            selUsuario.execute("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correou = %s", (id,))
            u = selUsuario.fetchone()
            if u is not None:
                User(u[0], u[1], u[2], u[3], u[4])
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex)
```

This the code of my form in html

```
<!-- Modal Log In-->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Iniciar Sesion</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <form  method="post" action="/login" class="row g-3">
      <div class="modal-body">
        {% with mensajes = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if mensajes  %}
            {% for m in mensajes %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          {{m}}
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa-solid fa-at" style="color: #9462a2;"></i></span>
          <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="email" name="correou"  class="form-control" id="floatingInputGroup1" placeholder="Username">
            <label for="floatingInputGroup1">Email</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa-solid fa-key" style="color: #9462a2;"></i></span>
          <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="password" name="claveu" class="form-control" id="floatingInputGroup1" placeholder="Username">
            <label for="floatingInputGroup1">Contraeña</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">

      <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
        <button class="btn" t style="background-color: #9462a3;" type="submit">Continuar</button>
       
      </div>

      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-3 mx-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"><i class="fa-brands fa-google" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
      
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fynally this is my code for the controller

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, logout_user
from config import config
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from models.ModelUser import ModelUser
from models.entities.User import User

mentalApp = Flask(__name__)
db = MySQL(mentalApp)
lmMental = LoginManager(mentalApp)

@lmMental.user_loader 
def loader_user(id):
    return ModelUser.get_by_id(db, id)


@mentalApp.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@mentalApp.route('/home')
def buscando():
    return render_template('buscando.html')

@mentalApp.route('/sigin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sigin(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        regUsuario = db.connection.cursor()
        nombreu = request.form['nombreu']
        correou =  request.form['correou']
        claveu = request .form['claveu']
        claveCifrada = generate_password_hash(claveu)
        regUsuario.execute("INSERT INTO usuario (nombreu, correou,claveu) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(nombreu, correou, claveCifrada))
        db.connection.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
    
@mentalApp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'] )
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usuario = User(0, None, request.form['correou'], request.form['claveu'], None)
        usuarioAut = ModelUser.login(db, usuario)
        if usuarioAut is not None:
            
            if usuarioAut.claveu: 
                login_user(usuarioAut)
                if usuarioAut.perfilu == 'A':
                    return render_template('admin.html')
                else:
                    return render_template('usuario.html')
            else:
                flash('Contaseña incorrecta')
                return redirect(request.url)
        else:
            flash('Correo incorrecto')
            return redirect(request.url)
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mentalApp.config.from_object(config['development'])
    mentalApp.run(debug=True, port=3300)
```